# Laravel 8 - Connection to SQL Database successful, but can not query

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-8

I've just set up a new Laravel 8 API project and I'm experiencing issues with trying to access a SQL database connection from my local machine on a Mac.

This is where I am at:

1. I've added the correct DB details to the .env file
2. Created a simple route (routes/api.php)

```
Route::get('users',[UserController::class,'index']);
```

3. Created a Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class UserController extends Controller
{
    function index() {
        if(DB::connection()->getDatabaseName())
        {
        echo "connected successfully to database ".DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
        }
    }
}
```

This returns the success message.

But if I add the following inside the index function to display some records from my users table:

```
return DB::select('select * from users');
```

When trying to view the application via Postman or through the browser, the application doesn't load, no apparent errors it just times out.

Am I missing any additional configuration details? Thanks

Comment: are you able to run your command on tinker? php artisan tinker

Comment: @AnuratChapanond I've tried and its returning the following error: Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out (SQL: select * from users)'